# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined" in ngrx store with angular only in production build

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am having anissue but only after production build at runtime. Now I am not sure if this is a bug or if I am doing a mistake. 
I get the error " "TypeError: Cannot read property 'release' of undefined"." in the console (browser), if I load the following feature module with ngrx (at runtime):

```
    import { AccountDto } from '../../../dto';
import * as fromAccountActions from '../actions/account.actions';

export interface AccountState {
  loading: boolean;
  loaded: boolean;
accountItems: AccountDto[];
}

export const initialState: AccountState = {
  loading: false,
  loaded: false,
  accountItems: []
};


export function accountReducer(
  state = initialState,
  action: fromAccountActions.AccountActions
): AccountState {

  switch (action.type) {
    case fromAccountActions.LOAD_ACCOUNT: {
      // console.log(action.type);
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    }

    case fromAccountActions.LOAD_ACCOUNT_FINISHED: {
      console.log('Finished: ' + action.payload);
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: true,
        accountItems: action.payload
      };
    }

    case fromAccountActions.LOAD_ACCOUNT_FAILED: {
      return {
        ...state,
        loading: false,
        loaded: false,
        accountItems: []
      };
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const getAccountItems = (state: AccountState) => state.accountItems;
export const getAccountLoading = (state: AccountState) => state.loading;
export const getAccountLoaded = (state: AccountState) => state.loaded;
```

index.ts in reducers

```
import * as fromReducer from './account.reducers';
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { createFeatureSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface AccountState {
  account: fromReducer.AccountState;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<AccountState> = {
  account: fromReducer.accountReducer
};

export const getAccountState = createFeatureSelector<AccountState>('account');
```

account.selectors.ts

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromReducer from '../reducers/account.reducers';
import * as fromFeature from '../reducers';

export const getCompleteAccountState = createSelector(
  fromFeature.getAccountState,
  (state: fromFeature.AccountState) => state.account
);
export const getAccountLoading = createSelector(
  this.getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountLoading
);
export const getAccountLoaded = createSelector(
  this.getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountLoaded
);
export const getAllAccountItems = createSelector(
  this.getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountItems
);
```

account.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { ThirdPartyModule } from '../thirdParty/thirdParty.module';
import { SharedModule } from './../shared/shared.module';
import { AccountListComponent } from './account-list/account-list.component';
import { AccountRoutesModule } from './account.routes';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { reducers, AccountEffects } from 'app/+account/store';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    SharedModule,
    AccountRoutesModule,
    ThirdPartyModule,
    TranslateModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('account', reducers),
    EffectsModule.forFeature([AccountEffects])
  ],

  declarations: [AccountListComponent],
  providers: [],
  exports: []
})
export class AccountModule {}
```

Help would be very much appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: where is the property `release` is used, I can't find them in the code

Comment: Me neither, this is something from inside angular or ngrx. This is why its only happening in production environment, if I do "... --prod" on the angular CLI

Comment: It will validate the run time properties doing a production build

Comment: So that means that this is any run time property issue?

Comment: Take a look within your console (ng serve). If you've got warning(s) regarding some circular dependencies in your selectors it's coming from there.

Comment: @FabianGosebrink I recently faced this problem and I fixed it by `importing` the reducer from the reducer file instead of the barrel file

Comment: @maxime1992 the direct import from the reducer file `import * as fromAccount from {app/+account/store/account.store` should resolve the circular dependencies

Answer (score 12):

I got this same error when using NgRx when I was importing files form barrel files.

When you're inside of a state feature, if you are in a file that imports one of the exports from the barrel `index.ts` file, you can get this error. You should be importing from the relative path when importing inside of the feature folder. Only files outside of the feature folder should use the barrel file to import things.

I didn't explicitly do the import. My IDE did it automatically. Took half a day to figure out.

Comment: Thank you very much @frosty. That was exactly my problem. I had import from barrel instead of a relative path import in one of the selectors and all of the unit tests for the selectors in the same nx lib were failing with that mysterious error :) cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The "this" statement is wrong in that case.

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromReducer from '../reducers/account.reducers';
import * as fromFeature from '../reducers';

export const getCompleteAccountState = createSelector(
  fromFeature.getAccountState,
  (state: fromFeature.AccountState) => state.account
);
export const getAccountLoading = createSelector(
  getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountLoading
);
export const getAccountLoaded = createSelector(
  getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountLoaded
);
export const getAllAccountItems = createSelector(
  getCompleteAccountState,
  fromReducer.getAccountItems
)
```

works. Thank you everybody.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You have extra `+` sign in your imports.

In `account.module.ts`:

```js
import { reducers, AccountEffects } from 'app/+account/store';
```

Try to remove it, it should solve the problem